# Can i create rmarkdown documents dynamicaly?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to create a rmarkdown template that is different depending on the input of the user. In my case a document describing your dataset. If someone has 20 variables, there should be 20 headings with the name of those variables. It then opens that template to allow a user to add some more information.

I do not mean [parameterized reports](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html).

Is that possible with a combination of sink() ?

#### update for a more worked out example

My idea is to have a set of functions that perform some summary per variable,
f.i. for numeric variables mean, median etc and for factor variables, an overview of factors. I can write all those functions, and I can make a rmarkdown document, but what I would really like is something like this.

dataset one

`letters numbers factors 
a 10 orange
b 3  green
c 6  verydarkblue`

With a rmarkdown file

```
This dataset has 3 variables with some properties
*information for author*
add information about where you found the data what the properties
are and add some background information to the variables.

\newpage
### letters
letters has [some code that executes summary function for letters]

### numbers 
numbers has [some code for numeric variables]
```

And If the number of variables are different, the template would be different

Comment: Well, you can write anything to a file using `cat`, or use `package:brew` to make templates which you can fill in using R objects. Any chance of a more concrete example of what you want to do?

Comment: I think the [rapport package](http://rapport-package.info) that we started around 5 years ago to power rapporter.net might fit your needs. Although it's not under heavy development right now, but is used in a number of production environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably start with the `knitr` package, which will already do some of what you want.  Then you create a code block with the output type set to `"asis"` so that tells `knitr` to put the results directly in the output file without adding any markup, then your code can insert the appropriate markup, just loop through the data set and output `### columnname` for each column, then the appropriate summary information.

The code block might look something like:

````
```{r, results="asis"}
for( i in seq_len(ncol(dataset)) ) {
  cat("### ", names(dataset)[i], "\n\n")
  if(class(dataset[[i]]) == 'numeric') {
    cat(mean(dataset[[i]]),'\n')
  } else if(class(dataset[[i]])=='factor') {
    print(table(datset[[i]]))
  } else {
    cat('Something Else\n\n')
  }
}
```
````

Comment: This looks very promising, I will do some tests and report back. Thank you.